# Mapview appears only when started with intent(tabhost)

Tags: android, maps, android-tabhost

I'm using a mapview inside FragmentActivity and the map only appears if it is called by intent. In the tabhost tab it stays blank.GetHttpResponse provides the data.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_dua);

    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume();
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    new GetHttpResponse(MyMapFragment1.this).execute();

    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"

    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: Did you override all the methods like said in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)? `onCreate(Bundle), onResume()` and so on

Comment: Ah I haven't, what should be inside those methods ?

Comment: You just have to call `mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` inside your fragment `onCreate`, same goes for all the methods written in the docs

Comment: Alright, did all of that, same result.